# Flawed reasoning between closed contour integral and Cauchy's residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Thanks for any help in advance.

I'm trying to justify the answer to :

$$\oint_V \frac{e^{3z}}{z-\ln2} \,dz$$

over the square of vertices $\pm$$1$$\pm$$i$.

By the Cauchy's integral theorem, 
as there is a simple pole at $z = \ln  2$, so

$$\oint_V \frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}} \,dz$$

becomes $2\pi  i\cdot e^{3ln2} = 16\pi i$

However, if you expand $e^{3z}$, we have a fraction of

$$ \frac{1 + (3z) + \frac{(3z)^{2}}{2} + ...}{z-\ln2} $$

which gives us a residue of $1$ at $z = \ln 2$.

Then, by the residue theorem 
$$\oint_V f(s) \,ds$$ $ = 2\pi \cdot $ (sum of residues) $= 2\pi i \cdot (1)$

which gives us an answer of $ 2\pi i$

What is the flaw in my reasoning? Have i applied the residue theorem wrongly?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the pole is outside the contour?

Comment: @asdf $0<\ln2<1$. The pole is inside the contour.

Comment: the pole's at ln2, which is roughly 0.693, inside the square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expanding $e^{3z}$ around $z=0$. You should expand it around $z=\ln2$.

Comment: what's problematic about expanding $e^{3x}$ about z = 0?

Comment: To find the residue at a pole $z_0$, you need the Laurent expansion in powers of $z-z_0$. The residue is the coefficient of $1/(z-z_0)$.